# Reducer is not updating the store

Tags: reactjs

Looks like my reducer is not updating the store. Any idea why that would be happening?

```
import 'babel-polyfill'

const initialState = {
    user: {
        name: 'Username', 
        Avatar: '/img/default/avatar.png'
    },
    friendsList: []
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {


        case 'setUserInfo' : 
            // If I console.log action.user here, I see that I'm getting good user data
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                user: action.user
            })
        default: return state

    }
}
```

Comment: `Object.assign({}, state, { user: action.user })` can be rewritten as `{...state, user: action.user}` ([spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), that's also the syntax that most people use in `react-redux`)

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer is not having any problem it will update the state and returning the correct one.

Please make sure that you have the following codes present.

create an action creator like this

```
var updateUser = function (user) {
    return {
        type: 'setUserInfo',
        user: user
    }
}
```

Create a store importing your reducer

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import userReducer from 'your reducerfile'
let store = createStore(userReducer)
```

You must need to dispatch the action by

```
store.dispatch(updateUser({name: 'some', Avatar: '/image/some'}));
```

Comment: Isn't your code essentially the same as mine -- just using a more terse version of Object.assign?